# Django Admin Add Object - Customize Dropdown

Tags: django, django-admin

Moin Moin!

I have this model in my models.py:

```
class BranchChief(models.Model):
    BranchChiefID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    BranchID = models.ForeignKey('Branch', db_column='BranchID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When adding a new object I get a dropdown-field for the field BranchChiefID showing all available usernames.

How can I change it to show first_name and last_name to identifiy the user in the dropdown-field? (username is (and must be) a random-number)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my initial problem statement :

add this to models.py:

```
def get_user(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name + ' (' + self.username + ')'

User.add_to_class("__str__", get_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I use the extension 'django-dynamic-raw-id'.
Thats not exactly what I wanted but works for me.